GraphQL: There can be only one argument named '...'
I'm new to GraphQL and I want to use it from the following documentation section: Query syntax 
Here is my code:
query marketplaceJobPostings(
  $pagination_eq: MarketplaceJobFilter,
  $searchExpression_eq: MarketplaceJobFilter
) {
  marketplaceJobPostings(
    marketPlaceJobFilter: $pagination_eq 
    marketPlaceJobFilter: $searchExpression_eq
  ) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        amount {
          rawValue
        }
        ciphertext
        skills {
          name
        }
        description
        title
        job {
          contractTerms {
            contractType
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm getting the following error:

Validation error (DuplicateArgumentNames@[marketplaceJobPostings]) : There can be only one argument named 'marketPlaceJobFilter'

Can anyone explain to me please what is wrong and why I cannot pass 2 arguments with the type marketPlaceJobFilter?

You need to combine your filters into a single input object and then use that as single argument.
input CombinedMarketPlaceJobFilter {
  pagination: MarketplaceJobFilter
  searchExpression: MarketplaceJobFilter
}

query marketplaceJobPostings(
        $combinedFilter: CombinedMarketPlaceJobFilter
      ) {
        marketplaceJobPostings(
          marketPlaceJobFilter: $combinedFilter
        ) {
          totalCount
          ...
        }
      }


I tried it and I'm getting "message": "Validation error (NonExecutableDefinition) : Type 'CombinedMarketPlaceJobFilter' definition is not executable",

You have to ensure that your GraphQL schema includes the CombinedMarketPlaceJobFilter input type definition.

yes I did see here please https://i.ibb.co/C2KV9Rj/Capture.png

I fixed it as following:
query marketplaceJobPostings(
  $filters: MarketplaceJobPostingsSearchFilter
) {
  marketplaceJobPostingsSearch(
        marketPlaceJobFilter: $filters
  ) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        amount {
          rawValue
        }
        ciphertext
        skills {
          name
        }
        description
        title
        job {
          contractTerms {
            contractType
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 

